# Java: combined sorting-functions calculate wrong results

Tags: java, numbers, repeat

I have a program which generates rows of 6 numbers (int arrays).
I am passing the output to another program that sorts it with the BubbleSort algorithm and writes it into a textfile.
If the first program is used without passing it works fine, no repeated numbers no zeroes. but when sorted there are repeated numbers and even i have seen zeroes, the case of the zeroes i could not reproduce atm, but the double occuring numbers. Could it have something to do with multithreading/parallel processing or the environment in whicht it is executed and which consist of a amd multicore win 10 host and deb jessie guest.

`java LottoArray | java  BubbleSort>test2.txt` **//terminal**

**test2.txt**

```
2 13 16 20 27 40 
9 14 17 21 25 41 
6 11 11 19 27 44 
4 10 25 34 39 47 
11 12 17 36 44 48 
1 15 23 31 39 40 
3 22 22 23 33 45 
1 25 26 26 35 49 
11 14 24 25 41 49 
6 6 14 17 38 46 
4 19 19 28 35 39
```

As you can see the sixs in the row before the last row are double and the 22s  and the 11s.

```
public class LottoArray{

    public static void main (String [] args){

    for(int o=0;o<=10;o++){
        int Reihe [] = new int [6];
        int zahl;

        int j=0;
        int i= 0;

        while(j<Reihe.length){
            zahl = (int) (Math.random()*50);
             boolean schonda = false;
            while ( i<j){
                if(Reihe[i]== zahl) 
                    schonda=true;
                i++;
            }

            if(schonda==false && zahl !=0){
                Reihe[j]=zahl;
                j++;}
        }

       for(int z=0;z<6;z++){
            System.out.print(Reihe[z]+" ");
    }   
    System.out.println();

    }  

   }
}
```

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int arr[]= new int[6];
    while(!StdIn.isEmpty()){

           for(int i=0;i<6;i++)

         arr[i]= StdIn.readInt();
        boolean getauscht;

        do {
            getauscht= false;       


            for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {

                if ( arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
                    int tmp = arr[i];   
                    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                    arr[i+1] = tmp;
                    getauscht = true;
                }
            }

        }while(getauscht); 


        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" " );
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

if i use the code without the bubbleSort and stream the output into a textfile, there are no repeated numbers and no zeroes, as it should be not possible because i coded the condition `if(schonda==false && zahl !=0)`

```
15 2 20 5 26 34 
13 6 15 33 12 37 
44 17 16 23 40 25 
25 47 10 43 40 44 
25 29 3 30 10 41 
32 1 23 35 43 28 
9 34 28 32 33 25 
5 46 31 16 25 9 
9 13 16 18 40 5 
29 15 16 2 16 15 
34 33 44 13 43 48
```

has someone experiences with that kind of occurring numbers that should not ?

Comment: Hi, even you seem knowing about styling text with `MarkDown` your question was a bit messed up, I corrected and think it's much easier to read. For future-questions you can look up here how to style with `MarkDown`: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thank you very much for your corrections, it seems seems so more than i do. I will try to consider it next times. Even it is easier to read now still no one seems to know what is going wrong.

Comment: You're welcome, perhaps you've now more luck, I still changed the headline ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is in this block of LottoArray:

```
int j=0;
int i= 0;

while(j<Reihe.length){
    zahl = (int) (Math.random()*50);
    boolean schonda = false;
    while ( i<j){
        if(Reihe[i]== zahl) 
            schonda=true;
        i++;
    }

    if(schonda==false && zahl !=0){
        Reihe[j]=zahl;
        j++;
    }
}
```

- The first time you enter in the `while (i<j){` loop from above (for the first element), both i and j are 0, so the loop is not executed.
- The second time (checking the second number), `i` is 0 and `j` is 1, so the loop is executed and `i` is increased.
- The third time (checking the third number), `i` is 1 and `j` is 2.
- Same for the rest, `i` is always `j-1`.

This is a bug, as you are not starting the check on the first element. I suppose you are only getting duplicates using the BubbleSort out of luck, as the error is not there.

To fix this, initialize `i` inside the first `while`, in the same place as the `schonda` var, not above with `j`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, which i find very reasonable. I should have seen it by my self, as this kind of errors are common. But in the final part you suppose me to initialize ```i``` which is of the integer typ, with ```schonda``` which is boolean., i will try to use ```while( i<=Reihe.legth-1)```

Comment: What I meant is that you should put the initialization of `i` in the same place that `schonda` (one line above or below), not that you should use the value to do that. `int i=0` is fine.

Comment: At first thank you. Now with the initialization of '''i''' in the first while loop, it works. But i do not get why. Even if '''i''' is now initialized in the first while loop, it is still above the first iteration of '''j''', so that the first time entering in the loop both '''i''' and '''j''' should still be zero.